# Can anyone help me identify this car? I think it's a 1941 __________ 2 door coupe (Buick? Chevy?)

Tags: chevrolet, buick, vehicle-identification, coupe

Can anyone help me identify this car?
I think it's a 1941 __________ 2 door coupe (Buick? Chevy?)

And what does the small logo say on the left trunk rear?

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like a bottom end Buick

Answer (score 4):

It's a Nash; compare the lettering on the car's trunk logo with this better example from the Wikipedia page on Nash:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.  I followed your lead and found this pic of  a 1941 Nash Ambassador 600  2 door Slipstream. (https://www.pinterest.com/pin/528680443749651396/)